# What is the strength level of Madara's Susanoo?

Tags: naruto

Madara compares his Susanoo with the Tailed Beasts. We also know at one point of time, the 3rd Raikage had a chakra level comparable to that of a Tailed Beast. However, the difference in power of Madara's Susanoo and chakra level of the Third Raikage is huge.

So how do we comprehend the power level of Madara's Susanoo?

Comment: to be honest...I've done the researching, but when I saw on the Narutopedia, that Madara's Susano'o withstood a Ten Tailed jutsu, I was richer with another heart attack...so for this, visit http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha section Dojutsu....damn I hate the fillers and to be in this kind of disadvantage:<

Comment: @Rinneg4n I remember when the 9 tailed beastS pounded on madara, his Susano was broken. True his Susano did survive the Tenpenchii by the Ten Tailed beast, however that was not a concentrated attack. The conclusion i can draw is that, it is not stronger than say survive the attacks of the 9 tailed beasts. +1 for the Ten tails reference.

Comment: It's over 9000.

Comment: @BoyLittUp there are many instances and his sussanoo's power is very vast...... although some of his sussanoo's power have already been telecasted in telly

Answer (score 5):

Let's take a look at some instances where Madara manifested his Susanoo's power:

1. It can summon 2 meteors simultaneously which resulted to complete chaos.
2. His clones can summon Susanoo with ease.
3. His Complete Body - Susanoo is gigantic.
4. It can take down 5 Kages easily.

[image: First Meteor]

[image: Susanoo]

[**Tengai Shinsei**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tengai_Shinsei)

#### [Madara's Susanoo](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha#Mangeky.C5.8D_Sharingan) on Narutopedia

> Having awakened the power of both his Mangekyō, Madara could use Susanoo. He did not need to fully manifest it to benefit from its use: with just its ribcage he can withstand an Ultra-Big Ball Rasengan, and he could perform attacks with only its upper half. [...] His Susanoo wielded up to two (four in the anime) undulating blades that could be thrown, then maintained and controlled remotely. Madara can also produce Yasaka Magatama of varying sizes.
>
> [...]
>
> According to Madara, the full power of his Complete Body — Susanoo was comparable to that of the tailed beasts, and no one had lived to see it a second time. Madara was able to shape his stabilised Susanoo as an armour which he equipped unto the Nine-Tails in order to complement their respective abilities.

#### So is there any way to break his extraordinary defense?

> Yes. The increased defensive strength of Madara's final Susanoo's form can only be destroyed or even pierced by powerful techniques like Hashirama's Top Transformed Buddha <sup>[Ch. 626]</sup>.

<sup>Quoted from old version of [Madara Uchiha on Narutopedia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha?oldid=894574#Mangeky.C5.8D_Sharingan)</sup>

Comment: Yup those are definitely the feats of madara's Susanoo. However, i was looking for answers like what ^@Rinneg4n said in the above posts.( He levelled an entire mountain with a single swipe).I think it powers falls within the range of 4 tailed or 6 tailed beasts. This is a complete conclusion of mine. There could be a more appropriate answer though :).

Comment: @BoyLittUp i have cited few of his sussano's abilities......apparantly the power of his sussano is very vast

Answer (score 0):

We didn't really get to see Madara's Perfect Susanoo's true power, as he only Used it when the matter called for it... He never really pushed to use the perfect Susanoo, as seen when he said it'd be a shame to use it twice after being interrupted in the battle against the five kages, so we don't know Madara's full powers as yet, when it was crushed by the nine tailed beasts, he wasn't even in its perfect form so you can't really judge the power because Madara, was never really ushed to use it to that extent.

Comment: would you mind but references are needed to support an answer

Answer (score -3):

I believe madaras susanoo was strong but I also believe that when Sasuke obtained his, it was already past madaras level. Madaras may have leveled mountains but Sasuke took out multiple meteorites the size of mountains with ease, and his could also fly. Not to mention his wasn't only manifested from an EMS but also a Sharinnegan. Which was SO6P powered. Sasukes susanoo wins by a long shot. Madaras as of what we saw of him also couldn't use Amaterasu, which Sasuke is able to do as well as shape. Sasuke also could stream his chakra chidori through his susanoo and match the size of the chidori with his susanoos hand. Which is a massive chidori. Not to mention he created two of the most powerful techniques in naruto, his perfect tailed beast susanoo and Indras arrow, rivaled only by narutos giant tailed beast bomb rasenshuriken. Sasuke as an adult we can only imagine is more developed and stronger. His susanoo is much more refined.

Answer (score -4):

Madara's tempestuous god of valor strength is comparable to that of the bijuu as it has very humongous chakra output.

one single swing of madara's susanoo can level or alter the continent.

if his susanoo can level mountains in a single swing of his blade then what would happen if madara put maximum power in his susanoo??

What if his(madara)susanoo had gone fullburst or full on??! Give a thought on that ..well ,"comparable to that of a bijuu "is too much but... OVERWHELMING*!!

Madara's susanoo is destruction incarnate- indra otsutsuki had passed on his descendants a very powerful ability to those who had achieved mangekyo sharingan and attained the EMS..the susanoo is an abilty based on the user's chakra control as well as one's emotion.. Hence it is a very powerful technique..sasuke's susanoo is also another incarnate of highly catastropic calamity.. Every MS and EMS users who attaind and manifests susanoo is outright powerful..madara's susanoo is as strong as his chakra reserve & also powered by his emotions & battle experience-- that makes his susanoo stronger than sasuke's in terms of battle exp...madara's susanoo power level points> power- 9, def -10 , durability-9 ,chakra usage- medium,destruction capability-extreme**

Comment: As it is now, your answer doesn't seems like answering the question. Consider editing it to fit the question more. Also, please refrain from using question sentence as an answer is suppose to answer the question and not asking another thing.